# Where is Flash player installed?

Tags: windows, file-management, flash

Flash develop requires flash player path I cannot find it.

Comment: I've asked the same question about OSX on *Ask Different*: [Where is Flash installed on OSX?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251013/where-is-flash-installed-on-osx)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`%SystemRoot%\System32\Macromed\Flash` on 32-bit systems

`%SystemRoot%\SysWow64\Macromed\Flash` on 64-bit systems

On most systems, `%SystemRoot%` points to `C:\Windows`. If you upgraded from NT or 2000, then it will be `C:\WINNT`.

Answer (score 0):

Opera's plugin is here:

```
C:\Program Files\Opera\program\plugins\NPSWF32.dll
```

Answer (score -1):

The Stand alone version (Flash Player.exe) doesn't exist on the computer. You have to watch flash files open them whit opera o IExplorer having the plug-ins.